# Tracking_codes in developer account?

Tags: box-api

I am developing new application with user management on Box and I want to use the "tracking_codes" user attributes. I've found that tracking codes capabilities has to be enabled in Enterprise settings https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/201506186-What-Are-User-Tracking-Codes- but instead of "Enterprise settings" (as can be seen in the first video on https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/201004483-Best-Practice-Managing-Users at time 00:21) I see only "Upgrade" menu.

Are tracking_codes functionality available for developer account? If yes, how to enable it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Tracking codes are available on developer accounts.

However, Tracking codes can only be enabled by Box on your account. It is not a self-service enablement. Open a ticket with Box support, and we can get it turned on for your development account.